# How to share a post's content in android?

Tags: android, mysql, android-recyclerview

I have a recycelerview that get JSON data from mySQl database online and I want to have a share button for each post that can share each post's content ,as you see i used "ACTION_SEND" codes but it doesn't share my content and just share the body sentence(the exact sentence that is in sharedBodyText),please tell me how can i share my post?here is my codes:
codes for the page that shows full post:

```
public class full_post extends AppCompatActivity {
Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_post);


    Intent intent=getIntent();


    int id=intent.getIntExtra(koreDatabaseOpenHelper.COL_ID,0);



    String title=intent.getStringExtra(koreDatabaseOpenHelper.COL_TITLE);
    String content=intent.getStringExtra(koreDatabaseOpenHelper.COL_CONTENT);
    String date=intent.getStringExtra(koreDatabaseOpenHelper.COL_DATE);


    TextView titleTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.post_title);
    TextView contentTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.post_content);
    TextView dateTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.post_date);


    titleTextView.setText(title);
    contentTextView.setText(content);
    dateTextView.setText(date);


}
public void shareText(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    String shareBodyText =(koreDatabaseOpenHelper.COL_CONTENT) ;
    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject/Title");
    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBodyText);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose sharing method"));

}}
```

codes of my DatabaseHelper :

```
public class koreDatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String TAG = "DatabaseOpenHelper";


private static final String DATABASE_NAME="db_kdramadl";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

private static final String POST_TABLE_NAME="tbl_posts";

public static final String COL_ID="col_id";
public static final String COL_TITLE="col_title";
public static final String COL_CONTENT="col_content";
public static final String COL_DATE="col_date";

private static final String SQL_COMMAND_CREATE_POST_TABLE="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+POST_TABLE_NAME+"("+
        COL_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
        COL_TITLE+" TEXT,"+
        COL_CONTENT+" TEXT, "+
        " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, "+
        COL_DATE+" TEXT);";

Context context;
public koreDatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {
        db.execSQL(SQL_COMMAND_CREATE_POST_TABLE);
    }catch (SQLException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: "+e.toString() );
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}


public boolean addPost(Post post){
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COL_ID,post.getId());
    cv.put(COL_TITLE,post.getTitle());
    cv.put(COL_CONTENT,post.getContent());
    cv.put(COL_DATE,post.getDate());

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=this.getWritableDatabase();
    long isInserted=sqLiteDatabase.insert(POST_TABLE_NAME,null,cv);

    Log.i(TAG, "addPost: "+isInserted);

    if (isInserted>0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

public void addPosts(List<Post> posts){
    for (int i = 0; i < posts.size(); i++) {
        if (!checkPostExists(posts.get(i).getId())) {
            addPost(posts.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my adapter :

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private List<Post> posts;

public PostAdapter (Context context, List<Post> posts){
    this.context = context;
    this.posts = posts;
}
@Override
public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.postha,parent,false);
    Typeface morvaridTypeface=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/morvarid.ttf");
    return new PostViewHolder(view,morvaridTypeface);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PostViewHolder holder, int position) {
   final Post post=posts.get(position);


    holder.title.setText(post.getTitle());
    holder.content.setText(post.getContent());
    holder.date.setText(post.getDate());


    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(context,full_post.class);
            intent.putExtra(koreDatabaseOpenHelper.COL_ID,post.getId());
            intent.putExtra(koreDatabaseOpenHelper.COL_TITLE,post.getTitle());
            intent.putExtra(koreDatabaseOpenHelper.COL_CONTENT,post.getContent());
            intent.putExtra(koreDatabaseOpenHelper.COL_DATE,post.getDate());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return posts.size();
}

public class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView title;
    private TextView content;
    private TextView date;

    public PostViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);


        content=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_content);


        date=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_date);

    }
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used below code to share post URL.You can use mUrl as your content.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,**mUrl**);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,getString("your apps title")));
```

**mUrl**(String) replace with Your **post content** (String)...

Comment: then how should i identify mUrl?(cause already has error), sorry i'm new in android so there are lots of things that i don't know

Comment: i did this and as you know in that position just we can put String ,so i tried to cast my textview to String but it has error ,http://uupload.ir/files/0bbs_casting.png

Comment: TextView tv = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.post_contant);

Comment: String mUrl = tv.getText().tostring();

Comment: yes i works just needed some changes as i did below :  String txt=((TextView)findViewById(R.id.post_content)).getText().toString();

Answer (score 1):

In your `full_post.class`, receive the extra passed from adapter,then create a button as share and then add this

```
 share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent what = new Intent();
            what.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            what.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Post Id:" + postId+ "\nPost 
            Title:" +postTitle);
            what.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(what, "Share with"));
        }
    });
```

where postId,postTitle are received as axtra from adapter class

Comment: get your postId like this postId= getIntent().getStringExtra(koreDatabaseOpenHelper.COL_ID);

Comment: better you remove that function and put the code in your onCreate

Comment: what exactly didnt work? can you paste the code here

Comment: i made my id as you said that it has the error that here we need int and you put String instead and here is the screenshot that i put the code into onCreat and again i have error ,http://uupload.ir/files/vzp6_nostring.png

Comment: use  getIntent.getIntExtra(koreDatabaseOpenHelper.COL_ID, -1); instead of getIntent().getStringExtra(koreDatabaseOpenHelper.COL_ID);

Comment: try making id as final

Comment: it doesn't work,anyway i found the correct way here is the way i had to cast my textview to string :   String txt=((TextView)findViewById(R.id.post_content)).getText().toString();